Выделение области и получение координат выделенной области на QGraphicsView в PyQt5
Пишу интерфейс на PyQt5.
Нужно реализовать на QGraphicsView, на которой находится QGraphicsScene, режим выделения области.
Пример на фото:

Нужно чтобы была возможность изменять размеры выделенной области с помощью точек на серединах ребер и углах области.
Область выделяется на загружаемой фотографии.
То есть нужно просто выделение области и получение координат выделенной области.
Если кто-то может подсказать как это можно сделать или видео похожие решения, то я буду благодарен за любые источники и ссылки на примеры.
Заранее спасибо.

Александр Трифонов, покажите то, что вы уже написали и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Как вариант:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QPen, QPixmap, \
    QPainterPath, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItem, \
    QGraphicsPathItem, QApplication, QGraphicsView, \
    QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsSimpleTextItem


class HandleItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, position_flags, parent):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, -3, -3, 6, 6, parent)
        
        self._positionFlags = position_flags

        self.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(81, 168, 220, 200)))
        self.setPen(QPen(
            QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 
            1.0, 
            Qt.SolidLine, 
            Qt.RoundCap, 
            Qt.RoundJoin
        ))
        self.setFlag(self.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

    def positionflags(self):
        return self._positionFlags

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        retVal = value
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange:
            retVal = self.restrictPosition(value)
        elif change == self.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            pos = value
            if self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.TopLeft:
                self.parentItem().setTopLeft(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Top:
                self.parentItem().setTop(pos.y())
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.TopRight:
                self.parentItem().setTopRight(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Right:
                self.parentItem().setRight(pos.x())
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.BottomRight:
                self.parentItem().setBottomRight(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Bottom:
                self.parentItem().setBottom(pos.y())
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.BottomLeft:
                self.parentItem().setBottomLeft(pos)
            elif self.positionflags() == SizeGripItem.Left:
                self.parentItem().setLeft(pos.x())
        return retVal

    def restrictPosition(self, newPos):
        retVal = self.pos()
        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Top or \
            self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Bottom:
            retVal.setY(newPos.y())

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Left or \
            self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Right:
            retVal.setX(newPos.x())

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Top and \
            retVal.y() > self.parentItem()._rect.bottom():
            retVal.setY(self.parentItem()._rect.bottom())
        elif self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Bottom and \
            retVal.y() < self.parentItem()._rect.top():
            retVal.setY(self.parentItem()._rect.top())

        if self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Left and \
            retVal.x() > self.parentItem()._rect.right():
            retVal.setX(self.parentItem()._rect.right())
        elif self.positionflags() & SizeGripItem.Right and \
            retVal.x() < self.parentItem()._rect.left():
            retVal.setX(self.parentItem()._rect.left())
        return retVal


class SizeGripItem(QGraphicsItem):
    Top = 0x01
    Bottom = 0x1 << 1
    Left = 0x1 << 2
    Right = 0x1 << 3
    TopLeft = Top | Left
    BottomLeft = Bottom | Left
    TopRight = Top | Right
    BottomRight = Bottom | Right

    handleCursors = {
        TopLeft: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
        Top: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        TopRight: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        Left: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        Right: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        BottomLeft: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        Bottom: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        BottomRight: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
    }

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self._handleItems = []

        self._rect = QRectF(0, 0, 0, 0)
        if self.parentItem():
            self._rect = self.parentItem().rect()

        for flag in (self.TopLeft, self.Top, self.TopRight, self.Right,
                     self.BottomRight, self.Bottom, self.BottomLeft, self.Left):
            handle = HandleItem(flag, self)
            handle.setCursor(self.handleCursors[flag])
            self._handleItems.append(handle)

        self.updateHandleItemPositions()
   
        self.posItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(
            '{}, {}'.format(self._rect.x(), self._rect.y()), parent=self)

    def boundingRect(self):
        if self.parentItem():
            self.posItem.setText(
                'x1={:.1f}, y1={:.1f}; x2={:.1f}, y2={:.1f};'.format(
                    self._rect.left(), self._rect.top(), 
                    self._rect.right(), self._rect.bottom()
                )
            )
            self.posItem.setPos(0, 0)            
            return self._rect
        else:
            return QRectF(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(127, 127, 127), 2.0, Qt.DashLine))
        painter.drawRect(self._rect)

    def doResize(self):
        self.parentItem().setRect(self._rect)
        self.updateHandleItemPositions()

    def updateHandleItemPositions(self):
        for item in self._handleItems:
            item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, False)

            if item.positionflags() == self.TopLeft:
                item.setPos(self._rect.topLeft())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Top:
                item.setPos(
                    self._rect.left() + self._rect.width() / 2 - 1,
                    self._rect.top())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.TopRight:
                item.setPos(self._rect.topRight())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Right:
                item.setPos(
                    self._rect.right(),
                    self._rect.top() + self._rect.height() / 2 - 1)
            elif item.positionflags() == self.BottomRight:
                item.setPos(self._rect.bottomRight())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Bottom:
                item.setPos(
                    self._rect.left() + self._rect.width() / 2 - 1,
                    self._rect.bottom())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.BottomLeft:
                item.setPos(self._rect.bottomLeft())
            elif item.positionflags() == self.Left:
                item.setPos(
                    self._rect.left(),
                    self._rect.top() + self._rect.height() / 2 - 1)
            item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

    def setTop(self, v):
        self._rect.setTop(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setRight(self, v):
        self._rect.setRight(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setBottom(self, v):
        self._rect.setBottom(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setLeft(self, v):
        self._rect.setLeft(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setTopLeft(self, v):
        self._rect.setTopLeft(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setTopRight(self, v):
        self._rect.setTopRight(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setBottomRight(self, v):
        self._rect.setBottomRight(v)
        self.doResize()

    def setBottomLeft(self, v):
        self._rect.setBottomLeft(v)
        self.doResize()


class CropItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QGraphicsPathItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self.extern_rect = parent.boundingRect()
        self.intern_rect = QRectF(0, 0, 
            self.extern_rect.width()/2, 
            self.extern_rect.height()/2)
        self.intern_rect.moveCenter(self.extern_rect.center())
        self.setBrush(QColor(10, 100, 100, 100))
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
        SizeGripItem(self)
        self.create_path()

    def create_path(self):
        self._path = QPainterPath()
        self._path.addRect(self.extern_rect)
        self._path.moveTo(self.intern_rect.topLeft())
        self._path.addRect(self.intern_rect)
        self.setPath(self._path)

    def rect(self):
        return self.intern_rect

    def setRect(self, rect):
        self._intern = rect
        self.create_path()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view.setScene(scene)
    
    pixmapItem = scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("lena3.png"))
    cropItem = CropItem(pixmapItem)
    
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    view.show()
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    view.setFixedSize(view.size())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



lena3.png


@АлександрТрифонов что не так?
